# Symfony, querybuilder, use extension from pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using `createQueryBuilder` with `Symfony` and `PGSQL`.

I installed the extension unaccent from PGSQL in my database with :

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

But when i try a query like :

```
                    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
                    $qb->select(array('a'))
                    ->from('ProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
                    ->where('unaccent(a.firstname) LIKE unaccent(?1) OR unaccent(a.lastname) LIKE unaccent(?1)')
                    ->setParameters(array(1 => '%'.$search.'%'))
                    ->setMaxResults(5);
            return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I have this error : `Error: Expected known function, got unaccent`

How can i use this extension with Symfony and Doctrine ?

Answer (score 5):

You may create your own DQL function to support Unaccent :

```
namespace Your\Namepsace\Doctrine\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * Unaccent string using postgresql extension unaccent : 
 * http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html
 * 
 * Usage : StringFunction UNACCENT(string)
 *
 */
class Unaccent extends FunctionNode
{
    private $string;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'UNACCENT(' . $this->string->dispatch($sqlWalker) .")";
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->string = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

}
```

You have to register it in doctrine configuration

**With Symfony**,

According [to the doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) :

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        dql:
            string_functions:
                unaccent: Your\Namespace\Doctrine\DQL\Unaccent
```

We also like to do automatically in bundle configuration, [see an example](https://github.com/Chill-project/Main/blob/master/DependencyInjection/ChillMainExtension.php#L64).

**With doctrine stand-alone**:

According [to the doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) (not tested) :

```
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->addCustomStringFunction('unaccent', 'Your\Namespace\Doctrine\DQL\Unaccent');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Doctrine2 extensions which will give you what you need (unaccent expression):  [Doctrine2 Extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions)

Comment: What i need ? Like what ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud check it pls: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html